# How to find duplicate rows if one of two certain columns are equal.. and a third & fourth column are equal?

Tags: sql, sql-server, duplicates, common-table-expression

Let's say I have a table with columns: A, B, C & D

Any two rows are considered a duplicate if:

A, B, C have equal values but not D

or

A, B, D have equal values but not C.

How do I get a set of duplicate rows? Using a CTE is OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do it with `union all` with the corresponding `where` conditions.

```
select * from tablename where a=b and b=c and a<>d
union all
select * from tablename where a=b and b=d and a<>c
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a self join it's quite easy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM TableName t1
INNER JOIN TableName t2 
    ON  T1.A = T2.A 
    AND T1.B = T2.B 
    AND (T1.C = T2.C OR T1.D = T2.D)
```

Assuming, of course, that if all 4 columns are equal it's a duplicated row as well...

However, if for some strange reason these rows are not considered as duplicates, you can change the conditions in the ON clause to this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM TableName t1
INNER JOIN TableName t2 
    ON  T1.A = T2.A 
    AND T1.B = T2.B 
    AND (
        (T1.C = T2.C AND T1.D <> T2.D)
        OR (T1.C <> T2.C AND T1.D = T2.D)
    )
```

Comment: I think the second one is what he meant, he just shouldn't have called it `duplicates`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RANK()` to detect duplicates without having to select from the table twice :

```
SELECT s.* FROM (
    SELECT t.*,
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.a,t.b,t.c ORDER BY t.d) as d_dif,
           RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY t.a,t.b,t.D ORDER BY t.c) as c_dif
    FROM YourTable) s
WHERE s.d_dif > 1 or s.c_dif > 1
```

`RANK()` as opposed to `ROW_NUMBER()` deals with duplicates, so if `d` / `c` will be the same, both records will get the same rank and won't be selected.